# Hiding the selection in a WPF ListBox, keeping it in contained controls

Tags: wpf, resources, systemcolors

I'm using a ListBox to display a list of editable objects whose template contains, among other things, a ComboBox.

I used this common technique to hide the ListBox selection, which is not used for anything:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Resources>
      <Brush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">Transparent</Brush>
      <Brush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}">Transparent</Brush>
```

The problem is this messes with the ComboBox dropdown list selection.

I'd like to override these resources again in my template, specifying the original values (`SystemColors.HighlightBrush`, etc) instead of hardcoding them. How can I do that?

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SearchService:Criterion}">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
      <!--I know how to specify a hardcoded brush here,
          but not how to reference one from SystemColors-->
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I used this common technique to hide
>   the ListBox selection, which is not
>   used for anything

If you do not use the selection for *anything* you should just use an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
    Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
    Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlColor}" />
```

or

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
    Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
    Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlColorKey}}" />
```

To restore the brushes to their default colors.

Comment: I knew I wasn't very far. Thanks! :-)

Comment: And if the system colors change while your app runs, and you want your color to update, use `{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}`.

Comment: @Andrei - Good point, updated my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: +1 for answering the question; if someone actually needs selection this will be helpful.